# Process hangs on WinHttpReceiveResponse()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winhttp, winhttpcertcfg

My process hangs with the below callstack at WinHttpRecieveResponse(). This behaviour is inconsistent sometime it works for the same data and same use case. But most of the time it hangs likes below.

I have checked using the WireShark that response is received on machine. I can find the response in Wireshark. But the WinHttpRecieveResponse() is not able to receive that data.

Please help me to find the issue.

```
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject()   Unknown
KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!HTTP_USER_REQUEST::_HandleSyncPending(class PENDING_API_CALL *,unsigned long *) Unknown
winhttp.dll!HTTP_USER_REQUEST::RecvResponse(int,void (*)(void *,unsigned __int64,unsigned long,void *,unsigned long),unsigned long,unsigned __int64)    Unknown
winhttp.dll!WinHttpReceiveResponse()    Unknown
atimport.dll!winHTTPStream::DoWaitForResponse(btkTimeval waitTime) Line 525 C++
atimport.dll!btkHTTPStreamBase::IsResponse(btkTimeval Timeout) Line 301 C++
atimport.dll!btkHTTPStreamBase::CompleteOutput(bool Blocking) Line 608  C++
atimport.dll!UwgmServerCache_i::executeHttpRequest(btkHTTPStreamBase * connection, xstring & responseStr, xstring reqBody) Line 11207   C++
atimport.dll!UwgmUploadAction_i::getChapteredUploadDescriptorsFromServer() Line 4480    C++
atimport.dll!UwgmUploadAction_i::prepareForUpload() Line 4557   C++
atimport.dll!UwgmUploadAction_i::onWorkspaceActionStart() Line 6401 C++
atimport.dll!UwgmWorkspaceModificationAction_i::onWorkspaceModificationActionStart() Line 6965  C++
atimport.dll!UwgmWorkspaceAction_i::onStart() Line 3689 C++
atimport.dll!UwgmAction_i::run() Line 636   C++
atimport.dll!UwgmAction_i::start(xstring msg) Line 580  C++
atimport.dll!UwgmAction_i::execute(xstring msg) Line 494    C++
atimport.dll!UwgmAction_i::execute() Line 489   C++
atimport.dll!atwncintBaseUtils_uwgmcc::executeAction(xrchandle<UwgmClientConnectorAction> ccAction, xstring logStr) Line 533    C++
atimport.dll!atwncintWorkspace_uwgmcc::upload(xrchandle<UwgmUploadAction> uploader) Line 1166   C++
atimport.dll!atwncintWorkspace_uwgmcc::upload(xrchandle<xstringsequence> docCadNames, atwncintGhostResolutionOption ghostResolutionOption) Line 1231    C++
atimport.dll!atwncintWorkspace_uwgmcc::checkin(xrchandle<xstringsequence> docCadNames, xrchandle<xstringsequence> targetFolderPaths, const char * comment, xrchandle<atwncintPostCheckinOptionDict> postCheckinOpts, xrchandle<atwncintBaselineInfo> baseline, xrchandle<xstringsequence> addToBaselineNames, atwncintGhostResolutionOption ghostResolutionOption) Line 1324    C++
atimport.dll!Java_com_ptc_prowt_Implementation_atwncint_1k03_00024Workspace_checkin(JNIEnv_ * _env, _jobject * _self, _jobject * docNames, _jobject * targetFolderPaths, _jstring * comment, _jobject * postCheckinOptions, _jobject * baseline, _jobject * addToBaselineNames, _jobject * ghostResolutionOption) Line 8657 C++
000000000a681df0()  Unknown
000000000513d9f8()  Unknown
0000000000533468()  Unknown
000000002b64d490()  Unknown
000000002b7fde38()  Unknown
```

Comment: application wait for some data receiving. but no data received.

Comment: @RbMm  I checked that using wireshark. I can find the response there. the complete data is reached to my machine but not recieved by WinHttpRecieveResponse() api.

Comment: from this thread callstack visible only synchronous `WinHttpRecieveResponse`. are data is received by application, if yes, why event not set - all this invisible

Comment: No data is recieved by the application. WinHttpRecieveResponse(Microsoft API) is waiting for the the data

Comment: [mcve] required.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this problem.
Actually before this call there was bufferoverflow which was corrupting my heap. 
Fixing the bufferoverflow solved my problem.